# why doesn't TextNode have update value(set) method?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to modify the value of a `TextNode` using jackson.
But there is no such method in the API.
Then I try to use reflection to overcome the limitation:

```
public class TestModify {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException,
            NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        final String json = "[{},\"123123\",\"12456\"]";
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
        final Iterator<JsonNode> nodes = node.elements();
        while (nodes.hasNext()) {
            final JsonNode n = nodes.next();
            if (n instanceof TextNode) {
                final Field f = TextNode.class.getDeclaredField("_value");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                f.set(n, "updated");
            }
            System.out.println(n.getClass());
        }
        System.out.println(node);
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine and `println` shows:

```
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode
class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode
[{},"updated","updated"]
```

So why is there no update method in the original API?

Comment: As per other answer, this is conscious design: `TextNode` is designed to be immutable (similar to other non-structured value nodes). As such, trying to change its state is strongly discouraged; a new instance should be made and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must have been a design decision. A `TextNode` represents a JSON String. Like a Java `String`, they most likely decided that it should be immutable.

You can simply replace existing `TextNode` instances with new ones.

Comment: Thx,what you say makes sense.

Comment: How can I replace a textNode? `findValues("...");` gives a list of nodes (that are textNodes in my case). I want to replace those textNodes. How can I do that?

Comment: @yo_haha I don't think you'll be able to do that. You'll need to traverse the JSON object (`ObjectNode`) yourself.